# <input> is 'under' <p>, the <p> in which the <input> lies ignores its height

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour with my `<p>` tags. There's an `<input>` element within a `<p>`. All my `<p>` tags have a `height` of `15px` and my `<input>` element has a `height` of `16px`.

When I examine the page with Firebug it looks like the `<input>` element is above or under the `<p>` tags and not within one.

The page is XHTML 1.0 Transitional but the `<input>` element is not closed — unfortunately I can't change this because it's created by [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/).

I'm sorry but I can't provide an example.

Comment: “it looks like the <input> element is above or under the <p> tags and not within one” — I’m not quite sure what you mean. Could you show us some code that illustrates the problem using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: No i'm sorry I can't recreate this in a fiddle. But it somehow looks like the elements have different z-indexes and are layered although they're defined nowhere.

Comment: Is your HTML valid? http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: What exactly is the cause for your not being able to provide an example?

Comment: its xhtml 1.0 Transitional and the input element is not closed, but I can't change this because it's created by primefaces. May this be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `<p>` height to something higher than that of the `<input>`.

If that is not ideal, use `z-index` to put one in front of the other.

N.B you need to set `position: absolute` for all items you use the `z-index` property on.

Comment: It's a workaround setting the <p> under/above the <input> to the input's height but it's not the ultimate solution. Thank you for suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove height from p tags style

Comment: The height for the p-tags isnt't defined anywhere. For the p-Tags there's only the font-size set to 100% and display:block.

Comment: “The height for the p-tags isnt't defined anywhere.” Then what did you mean in the question when you said “All my <p> tags have a height of 15px”?

Comment: Font size is set to 12px and the font size of the <p> is set to 100% so it's automatically height is 15px when i look at it with firebug.